# How iterate whit NgFor an Object as Array? Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

I have this function

```
getItems(item : ItemStructure) {
    let keys : string[];
    this.afdb.list('/Items').valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data)
          item = data;
          keys = Object.keys(item);
    });
}
```

And ItemStructure is this:

```
export interface ItemStructure {
   description: string;
   itemname: string;
};
```

And in my Home.html I have this and I want to iterate with `NgFor`, but it is an Object

```
<ion-list class="itemlist" *ngFor="let key of keys; let i = index">
   <p>{{item[key].description}}</p>
   <p>{{item[key].itemname}}</p>
</ion-list>
```

I don´t know how to transform an Object to Array. I appreciate all help

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are assigning values to class properties instead method variables. In `getItems` method you are defining a local variable called `keys` and you are assigning the result of `Object.keys` instead to assign to `keys` class property. Same with `item`. Maybe the problem is for this reason.